# Grunt Autoprefixer: No Source Files Were Found

Tags: gruntjs

Not sure what I'm doing wrong... all of my other grunt tasks seem to be working no problem. Grunt and all packages are the most recent stable releases.

```
autoprefixer: {
    options: {
        browsers: ['last 8 versions']
    },
    dist: {
        files: {
            'assets/css/autoprefixed.css' : 'assets/css/source.css'
        }
    }
},
```

I have tested with several different files, all the same result. After running grunt, I get:

```
Running "autoprefixer:dist" (autoprefixer) task
Warning: No source files were found. Use --force to continue.
```

The referenced files are definitely in the correct locations. Anyone know what I might be doing wrong? I can include all of my grunt code if needed.

Comment: Name them `src` and `dst`. See [the doc](https://github.com/nDmitry/grunt-autoprefixer).

Comment: @grasGendarme Thanks! I did it the way in the docs and it worked. I was following along with a different article and assumed I had been doing things the right way. I was wrong :(

Answer (score 0):

Task configuration looks correct - I have just tried it, and it works for me(grunt 0.4.5 and autoprefixer 0.7.3).

The only suggestion I have, is that location `assets/css/source.css` is incorrect(it is relative to Gruntfile.js, unless the current working directory is changed)

Comment: Thank you for the help Bogdan! I ended up following @grasGendarme's suggestion and things seem to be working now.